# How to make tool tip content appear in a single line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a tooltip, applied with the title attribute like this :

```
<img src="myGif.gif" border="0"  class="tooltip" alt="Help"
title="This is a world of mad people who don't believe in what they are doing and as such they are extremely risky and will lead to the destruction of the society as we call it"/>
```

The problem is, I want the content to appear in one line , but it's breaking up in IE and Mozilla.

In ie(7 and 8) the content is getting rendered in three lines like this :

```
This is a world of mad people who don't believe in what they are doing
and as such they are extremely risky and will lead to the 
destruction of the society as we call it
```

In Mozilla , it's getting rendered  like this :

```
This is a world of mad people who don't believe in what they are doing and as such they are
extremely risky and will lead to the destruction of the society as we call it
```

But I want the content to be rendered in one single line.

So I need to use javascript or CSS or jquery to render to it. However, till now I have been unable to do so.

Comment: Just a thought: what if you replace spaces with `&nbps;`?

Comment: How do you render your tooltip? Do you just use the standard tooltip. I don't believe you can change the standard behavior. You can write a tooltip in Javascript and use 'white-space:nowrap'.

Comment: @AleksG Ok guys , thanks for the suggestion. 
I will apply these and let you know , if anything comes up .

Comment: No dice guys, after applying white-space:nowrap and &nbsp; , i was at least able to bring the content in two lines in both MF and IE. But single line content is not coming up. Is there any jquery solution that you guys can suggest for this ? I will re tag the Qs  with jquery. Huh ! Its becoming a nightmare.

Comment: You should not want to display overly long tool-tips on a single line. That's rather user-hostile behavior for a website, and unnecessary at that. What's the benefit?

Comment: @Tomalak  Well i dunno  about the benefit, but that's what my client wants. Creepy, i know :)

Comment: Well maybe you should advise your client that this is a bad idea. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak :: Well said :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be including something like `tooltip.css` file somewhere that defines the style of the tooltip. So set the default tooltip css to: `white-space:nowrap;`. That will force everything on one line, but it may cause the text to run off the element, so you will probably have to adjust the width of the tooltip as well (if you have tooltips elsewhere on your site and this is a special case, a smarter solution would be to create custom css for this case, and use that and leave the default css as it is for all other cases).

Comment: Yeah did that , does not bring in one line though, rather sets everything cross browser in two lines. Happy with that for the time being . Thanks .